# Principle of potentiometric titration

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox, titration, reduction-potential

In potentiometric titration between ascorbic acid and iodine, when we plot the graph of EMF with volume of iodine consumed, we get a sudden decrease in EMF at equivalance point--why? It is also negative--why?

Using Nernst equation at equivalence point we get
$$E_{cell}=E_{STP}~~~(voltage ~at ~STP)$$

What is its physical meaning?

Answer (score 1):

In potentiometric analysis, there are two electrodes, an indicator electrode (platinum here) where reduction takes place and reference electrode (calomel electrode) where
oxidation takes place.

So here the reference is not $E_{STP}$ cell but the $E_{cathode}$ that is the calomel electrode, so there is drop to $-241mV$ after the equivalance point. Hence,
 $E_{cell} = E_{cathode}$